# Replace Extra Zero Coldfusion Cfset

Tags: coldfusion

I am very new to Coldfusion and not sure what the format should be to use this function correctly.

I want to convert 0000411111 to 0411111 get rid of the first three zeros

```
<cfset origValue = "#query.column#"> 
<cfset newValue = ReReplace(origValue, "0+", "", "all")>
<cfoutput>#newValue#</cfoutput>
```

This removes all zeros is there anyway to just keep one zero. Just curious.

Thanks in advance for your assistances.

Answer (score 5):

If the string will always be 7 characters you can use

```
<cfset newValue = numberFormat(000411111,'0000000')>
```

If you don't know the length and always want to remove leading 0's and leave one at the begining you can do

```
<cfset newValue = '0' & int(000411111)>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you always want to remove the first three characters, you can use the `right()` function:

```
<cfset newValue = right(query.column, len(query.column)-3>
```

This will return all the characters from the right side of the string without the leading three characters.

Comment: What a nice little function! I'll have to remember that one. Thanks, Adam.

Comment: No worries. I've upgraded my comment to an answer, as it probably qualifies as a valid option.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it 2 different ways:

```
<Cfset newvalue=right(origvalue,len(origvalue)-3>
```

This method returns the string without the left 3 most characters

or

```
<Cfset newvalue=mid(origvalue,4,len(origvalue)-3>
```

this method starts at position 4 and grabs the rest of the string.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `numberFormat()` answer is the best one, but other people have been suggesting using `mid()` and `right()` which I think - whilst those approaches work - are more cumbersome than you need to make it. If you simply wish to remove the first three chars of the string, there's a [`removeChars()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e3e.html) function. It's unclear from your question though whether this actually achieves what you want: if it's only when the number is left-padded with too many zeros you want to do this, then the `numberFormat()` approach is best. If it's *any three characters*, then this approach is better.

```
newValue = removeChars(origValue, 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex string you are looking for really is for matching 2 or more 0's at the start of the string, and replacing them with simply a single 0.

This gives the regex `^0+0`

`^` matches the start of the string, `0+` matches 1 or more 0's, `0` matches the second zero.  This will mean that if there is only 1 leading zero then it won't need to do anything.  Finally you only need to do this once, as you are only replacing the ones at the start of the string. This brings to the CF code

`newValue = ReReplace(origValue, "^0+0", "0", "one")`

This should replace multiple leading zeros with a single one, while not adding zeros where there weren't any to begin with.

As a final note, a good place to play around with regex is http://gskinner.com/RegExr/